# Small function to rearrange string array in VBA

Tags: vba, solidworks

I've been writing a macro for Solidworks in VBA, and at one point I'd like to rearrange the sheets in a drawing in the following way--if any of the sheets are named "CUT", bring that sheet to the front. Solidworks API provides a way to [rearrange the sheets](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IDrawingDoc~ReorderSheets.html), but it requires an array of sheet names sorted into the correct order--fair enough. The way to get the sheet names looks to be this [method](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IDrawingDoc~GetSheetNames.html).

So, I tried to write a small function to rearrange the sheets in the way I want. The function call I'm trying to use and the function are shown here

Function Call

```
Dim swApp           As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swDrawing       As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
Dim bool            As Boolean

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swDrawing = swApp.ActiveDoc

.
.
.

bool = swDrawing.ReorderSheets(bringToFront(swDrawing.GetSheetNames, "CUT"))
```

Function Definition

```
Private Function bringToFront(inputArray() As String, _
    stringToFind As String) As String()

Dim i               As Integer
Dim j               As Integer
Dim first           As Integer
Dim last            As Integer
Dim outputArray()   As String

first = LBound(inputArray)
last = UBound(inputArray)

ReDim outputArray(first to last)

For i = first To last
    If inputArray(i) = stringToFind Then
        For j = first To (i - 1)
            outputArray(j + 1) = inputArray(j)
        Next j
        For j = (i + 1) To last
            outputArray(j) = inputArray(j)
        Next j
        outputArray(first) = stringToFind
    End If
Next i

bringToFront = outputArray

End Function
```

The error I get is "Type mismatch: array or user defined type expected" on the function call line. I've done quite a bit of searching and I think what I'm messing up has to do with static vs dynamic arrays, but I haven't quite been able to get to the solution on my own.

Comment: This probably wont solve your problem, but you should definitely `ReDim bringToFront(first to last)`, otherwise your code wont work if inputArray is not zero-based. This is all what I could see suspicious in your code.

Comment: BTW, why dont you simply use `Sheets("CUT").Move before:=Sheets(1)`? You can do some checking if Sheets("CUT") exists. or simply use *On Error Resume Next*

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll give your suggestion a try, but looking at the [sheet](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ISheet_members.html) members, I don't see Move among them. Am I missing something?

Comment: Move is a member of the Worksheet class. It will work ;), even if not proposed by Intellisense (often the case with these kind of calls).

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't an Excel Worksheet object, but a Solidworks Sheet object. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to do anything other than throw an error with the .Move method.

Comment: I suggest that to edit your post, correct the Redim statement and show explcitly the call statement and where it breaks

Comment: Well, thanks. I still dont see anywhere you call bringToFront. Could it be that you should `swDrawing.ReorderSheets(BringToFront(swDrawing.GetSheetNames), "CUT")`. Oh I see, there is another problem yet, it could be it.

Comment: Whoops, you're correct! Sorry about that, it's actually what I had originally but I was playing around with the function call before I posted here. I'll correct the call. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: This `bringToFront(j + 1) = inputArray(j)` looks too much like function call for the left part of the assignment. Usually you can use a local variable for retval instead w/o performance penalty esp. if last line is `bringToFront = retVal` no array copying takes place (only pointer fiddling).

Comment: @wqw yes that was the problem generating the error message, as indicated in my answer

Comment: @JDP please see my answer below for the problem that actually generated the error message, and a tested fix. Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the corrections suggested in the comments, what is happening is that at the lines

```
bringToFront(j + 1) = inputArray(j)
```

and

```
bringToFront(first) = stringToFind
```

the compiler thinks you are trying to call recursively the function bringToFront. That is why it complains about the number of parameters in the error message. To fix this, just create another array as local array variable, with a different name, let us name it "ret", fill it appropriately, and assign it at the end before returning.

EDIT: **Also, it is better to declare the arrays as Variant types to avoid interoperability problems between VB6 and .Net . This was the final issue**

```
Private Function bringToFront(inputArray As Variant, _
stringToFind As String) As Variant

    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim j       As Integer
    Dim first   As Integer
    Dim last    As Integer

    first = LBound(inputArray)
    last = UBound(inputArray)

    Dim ret() As String
    ReDim ret(first To last)

    For i = first To last
        If inputArray(i) = stringToFind Then
            For j = first To (i - 1)
                ret(j + 1) = inputArray(j)
            Next j
            ret(first) = stringToFind
        End If
    Next i
    bringToFront = ret
End Function
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I've corrected the function in the original question as per your suggestions here. Unfortunately, I still get the error about type mismatch when I try to call the function.

Comment: did you change the name of the variable as suggested in the fix?

Comment: @JDP If you did, it looks like we need to see the signature of the `swDrawing.ReorderSheets` function, and also the declaration of the variable `bool`!

Comment: I've included the definition of bool, but I'm not totally sure what you mean by the "signature" of `swDrawing.ReorderSheets`. [This](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IDrawingDoc~ReorderSheets.html) is it's page in the API manual. Is that what you're after? Thanks again.

Comment: @JDP it seems it is a problem of marshalling between VB6 and VB.Net. We need to try using Variants instead of arrays (see the edited version of the signature of bringToToFront), and to determine where exactly is the problem, I mean when passing from .net to vb6 or vice-versa. Let us split the call into two calls: dim newOrder as Variant, newOrder = bringToFront(...), then cal ReoderSheets(newOrder)

Comment: Bingo, simply changing the definition to Variant was enough to get exactly the expected behaviour. I guess I've got my reading cut out for me tonight trying to figure out what exactly Variants are.

Comment: Great! so it was indeed a problem of interoperability. I suspected that when i saw the declaration of reorderSheets in the manual of sldWorks. As a conclusion, I think we should always use variants instead of explicit arrays when interoperating between VB6 and .Net. :)